# Returning List<Object> in HTML.BeginForm MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Hey Guys I need help on this, I know I can return `List<string>` in HTML.BeginForm which looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new {@class = "form-horizontal", role = "form"}))
{
<textarea name="logic" style="width: 10em; height: 10em;"></textarea>
<textarea name="logic" style="width: 10em; height: 10em;"></textarea>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
    </div>
</div>
}
```

I can return `List<string> Logic` on my Controller HTTPOST

But my question is how will I do it if I need to return a List of Object? Not using a Model because I need to return 2 Objects so I am was thinking like my controller should get it something like this

```
        public ActionResult Test(List<Model1> model1, List<Model2> model2)
```

Thanks for those who can help

Comment: Unclear what your asking. What are you models `Model1` and `Model2`?

Comment: `Model1` and `Model2` are just examples, let say they have 2 parameters which are `string1` and `string2` for each Model if it will make it clearer

Comment: Then the answer is yes, its easy to do

Comment: Can you explain your answer? if can please give example, will appreciate greatly

Comment: This site is for helping you with **your** code. Start with a view model containing 2 collection properties and then pass it to the view. Use a `for` loop or `EditorTemplate`'s for you model types and post back you view model.

Comment: I thought this site helps people to learn more and not give their code and let others fix it. Anyways an example would be a good way to understand the code, by your answer I did not understand anything because I do not have any reference to it.

Comment: You need read the help files to understand what SO is :)

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542107/pass-list-of-checkboxes-into-view-and-pull-out-ienumerable/29554416#29554416) for an example of generating controls in a `for` loop and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29486946/asp-net-mvc-parent-child-view-with-parent-view-updating-children/29487118#29487118) for using and `EditorTemplate`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do in provided way

First declare class

```C#
 public class TestModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; } 
    }
```

Second Controller to accept list of model

```C#
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Test(List<TestModel> model1, List<TestModel> model2)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Last, View to pass model values

```C#
@using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new {@class = "form-horizontal", role = "form"}))
{
<textarea name="model1[0].Name" style="width: 10em; height: 10em;"></textarea>
<textarea name="model1[0].Text" style="width: 10em; height: 10em;"></textarea>
<textarea name="model1[1].Name" style="width: 10em; height: 10em;"></textarea>
<textarea name="model1[1].Text" style="width: 10em; height: 10em;"></textarea>
<textarea name="model2[0].Name" style="width: 10em; height: 10em;"></textarea>
<textarea name="model2[0].Text" style="width: 10em; height: 10em;"></textarea>
<textarea name="model2[1].Name" style="width: 10em; height: 10em;"></textarea>
<textarea name="model2[1].Text" style="width: 10em; height: 10em;"></textarea>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Put the breakpoint inside Test controller you will see list populated

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to wrap these lists into a view model class like this -

```
public class ModelView
{
    public List<Model1> model1 { get; set; }
    public List<Model2> model2 { get; set; }
}
```

...and then the controller will look like -

```
public ActionResult Test(ModelView modelView)
```

Within the controller you can easily access the lists.

```
modelView.model1 
modelView.model2
```

Comment: Thats a good idea, but what will i put on the name and id of the html inputs? As much i do not like to use editorfor but in your solution i need to use @model to implement it

Comment: Bind your View from this ModelView class. Now you can easily have controls for this like - model.<propertyName> OR model.<propertyName>.<subpropertyName> etc for example. Comment from Steplen gives good hint

Answer (score 2):

If you want to generate a view with multiple model objects then you need to create a ViewModel comprising properties that are needed from those models. And then reference the view with this ViewModel.

```
public class Model1
{
    public string prop11 { get; set; }
    public string prop12 { get; set; }
}

public class Model2
{
    public string prop21 { get; set; }
    public string prop22 { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public List<Model1> model1 { get; set; }
    public List<Model2> model2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then generate the view referencing the viewmodel that will get the properties from both models.

controller action that will be hit from that view:

```
public ActionResult Test(ModelView modelView) // you can access the viewmodel properties
```