# updating data on one to many relation in EF core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I'm trying to update a table(FlightClasses) with multiple rows having relation of one to many with table(Flight) but i can't update it with the changed values
Can anyone help me with that

Model class of Flight
 i want to update rows on other table of flightclasses linked with row in this table

```
namespace Airline.Models
{
    public class FlightModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FlightName { get; set; }
        public string FlightNo { get; set; }
        public string OriginCity { get; set; }
        public string DestinationCity { get; set; }
        public DateTime Departure { get; set; }
        public DateTime Arrival { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<FlightClassesModel> FlightClasses { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Model class of FlightClasses

```
namespace Airline.Models
{
    public class FlightClassesModel
    {

        public int FlightClassesModelId { get; set; }
        public type Class { get; set; }
        public int AvailableSeats { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public virtual FlightModel Flight { get; set; }

        public int? FlightId { get; set; }
    }
    public enum type
    {
        Business_Class,
        First_Class,
        Club_Class
    }
}
```

View

```
@model Airline.Models.FlightModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

<h4>FlightModel</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FlightName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="FlightName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FlightName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FlightNo" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="FlightNo" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FlightNo" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="OriginCity" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="OriginCity" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="OriginCity" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="DestinationCity" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="DestinationCity" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="DestinationCity" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Departure" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Departure" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Departure" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Arrival" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Arrival" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Arrival" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            @foreach (var flightClass in Model.FlightClasses)
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="@flightClass.Class" class="control-label"></label>
                    <select class="form-control" asp-for="@flightClass.Class"  asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<type>()"></select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="@flightClass.Class" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="@flightClass.AvailableSeats" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="@flightClass.AvailableSeats" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="@flightClass.AvailableSeats" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="@flightClass.Price" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="@flightClass.Price" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="@flightClass.Price" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            }

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var flightModel = await _context.Flight.FindAsync(id);
            if (flightModel == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(flightModel);
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, FlightModel flightModel)
        {
            if (id != flightModel.Id)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(flightModel);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!FlightModelExists(flightModel.Id))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(flightModel);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

This code `_context.Update(flightModel);` will update flightModel only, so if you wanna update  FlightClasses also you must get FlightClasses from the flightModel then use `_context.Update(flightClasse);` for all the instances in FlightClasses. And at the end you use `await _context.SaveChangesAsync();`

Comment: when i get the data from view the flightClasses is shown empty no data attached with them

Comment: i'm also using the method of lazyloading

Comment: When you get your flightModel at the beginning (in the first method) the flightClasses  was empty also? if you use include to get flightClasses   with your flightModel.

Comment: but on the view the previous values of the FlightClasses are available

Comment: So your problem is that the form did not send the FlightClasses data to the controller in the second method. this post may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29486946/asp-net-mvc-parent-child-view-with-parent-view-updating-children

Answer (score 0):

**Updating data in the Parent-Child(one to many relation) table using EntityFramework Core**

we first retrieve the FlightModel entity from the database using FirstOrDefaultAsync

```
   var entity = await _context.FlightModel
                .Include(s => s.FlightClassesModel)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.FlightModelId == id);
```

use SetValues on the CurrentValues of the Entry method to update the properties of the FlightModel

```
 _context.Entry(entity).CurrentValues.SetValues(FlightModel);
```

Loop through the FlightClassesModel collection to update or add new child entities as needed.

```
foreach (var child in FlightModel.FlightClassesModel)
            {
                var childEntity = entity.FlightClassesModel.FirstOrDefault(c => c.FlightClassesModelId == child.FlightClassesModelId);
                if (childEntity != null)
                {
                    _context.Entry(childEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(child);
                }
                else
                {
                    entity.FlightClassesModel.Add(child);
                }
            }
```

SaveChangesAsync to persist the changes to the database.

```
 await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```