# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC page to create object with list of complex objects

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-mvc, domain-driven-design, .net-6.0

I have the following model, which needs to be created via a page:

```
public class Exercise
{
    public Guid Id{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description{ get; set; }

    public ICollection<ExerciseCategory> Categories
    ...
    public ICollection<Link> Links { get; set; }
}

public class ExerciseCategory
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Link
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I have a view that lets me create this object, but I miss a form control for the property `Exercise.Links`:

```
<form id="profile-form" method="post">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 p-sm-2 p-md-3 p-lg-5 bg-custom-white rounded-4">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-floating mt-2 mb-2">
            <input asp-for="Input.Name" class="form-control" />
            <label asp-for="Input.Name" class="form-label"></label>
            <span asp-validation-for="Input.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating mt-2 mb-2">
            <input asp-for="Input.Description" class="form-control" />
            <label asp-for="Input.Description" class="form-label"></label>
            <span asp-validation-for="Input.Description" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating mt-2 mb-2">
            <select asp-for="Input.CategoryIds" 
                    asp-items="Model.Input.Categories" class="form-control"></select>
            <label asp-for="Input.Categories" class="form-label"></label>
        </div>
        <button id="create-exercise-button" type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary">Create</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

The property `Exercise.Categories` is easy as `Category` is an entity which is created separately, so I just have a dropdown listing the existing categories.

`Link` is just a value object that is not persisted on its own. Therefore, the user should be able to create/remove/edit `Link` from the `Exercise` create/edit page.

I have tried the following:

```
            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Input.Links.Count; i++)
            {
                <div>
                    <input asp-for="Input.Links[i].Name">
                    <input asp-for="Input.Links[i].Value">
                </div>
            }
```

Which results in the following HTML:

```
<div>
  <input type="text" id="Input_Links_0__Name" name="Input.Links[0].Name" value="some link">
  <input type="text" id="Input_Links_0__Value" name="Input.Links[0].Value" value="https://somelink.com">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="Input_Links_1__Name" name="Input.Links[1].Name" value="some link1">
  <input type="text" id="Input_Links_1__Value" name="Input.Links[1].Value" value="https://somelink1.com">
</div>
```

But this doesn't populate the Input.Links property when posting back.

I started thinking that the problem is the fact that my list is a list of `Link` rather than a list of primitive types. In order to test this, I added a test `List<string>` to input model called `Links1` and tried to populate that list as I did before:

```
<div class="form-floating mt-2 mb-2">
  <input asp-for="Input.Links1[i]" data-val="true" class="form-control" />
  <label asp-for="Input.Links1[i]" class="form-label"></label>
</div>
```

This works. I get the populated list back in the controller after submitting the form, which confirms the problem is the `List<Link>`

**How can I add a form control for populating the property `Exercise.Link` (which is a `List<Link>`)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35326345/4220401), I figured out what the problem was:

> The class `Link`, on which the property `Exercise.Links` depends, has no setter for its `Link.Name` and `Link.Value` properties, so the binder cannot populate them when you submit the form.

This is due to `Link` being a domain model. The solution in this case was to create a presentation layer model that has public `{get; set;}` and use that on the form instead of the domain model.

So, to answer the question properly, this is how you could write a form control to edit a `List<Link>`:

```
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Input.Links.Count; i++)
        {
            <div>
                <input asp-for="Input.Links[i].Name">
                <input asp-for="Input.Links[i].Value">
            </div>
        }
```